# SQL Server Linked Database Aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to have not only a LinkedServer, but linked database and server?
My situation is that of having one environment with a setup of:

ServerX: DatabaseOne,
         DatabaseTwo

and another environment of:

ServerY: MyDatabaseOne,
         MyDatabaseTwo

Now, DatabaseOne and MyDatabaseOne are exactly the same, as are DatabaseTwo and MyDatabaseTwo.
I have a stored procedure that does some basic table updates from one db to the other on a given server, and I want it to be able to work in both evironments. I have set up a linked server so my reference can be:

MyLinkedServer.DatabaseOne.dbo.MyTable or MyLinkedServer.MyDatabaseOne.dbo.MyTable

Even with this though, I will need to change the SP when I switch environments to change the db names, is there any way of setting up a Database Alias, so that I can write:

SELECT * FROM MyLinkedServer.MyLinkedDatabase.dbo.MyTable

So that as long as LinkedServer and (if possible) LinkedDatabase are set up in each environment, the SP will work without changing when switching environments?

Comment: To learn about linked server and synonyms please refer
http://sqlblog.toolsoftonline.com/?p=78

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the short answer is no. I don't believe database aliasing is supported yet.

Dynamic SQL could do it. You could inject the database name etc and execute your query.

Comment: Thanks @Carl, I had a feeling that was going to be the answer.

Comment: Do the right thing Ben, and create another instance with the right database names!  :)

Answer (score 23):

You can avoid dynamic sql by Aliasing the server by following these steps (credits to [this post](http://alexpinsker.blogspot.com/2007/08/how-to-give-alias-to-sql-linked-server.html))

1) Step 1:

- In SQL Server Management Studio open Linked Servers and then 'New Linked Server'.
- Inside of appeared wizard – Select the General tab.
- Specify alias name in "Linked server" field.
- Select SQL Native Client as provider.
- Add sql_server in "Product Name" field (that's the magic).
- In "Data Source" – specify name of the host to be used as linked server.

2) Step 2:

- In Security tab – specify proper security options (e.g. security context)

3) Step 3:

- In Server Options tab – set "Data Access", "RPC", "RPC Out" and "Use Remote Collation" to true.

4) Step 4:

- Enjoy

You can take it one step further and skip specifying the database name when querying a table you can create synonyms for each object like this:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[DimProduct]
FOR
[AdventureWorksDW].[dbo].[DimProduct]
```

this will create DimProduct Synonyms in your database. As far as I know, you can't create a synonym to a database.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer to my problems. It's slightly more complex then just creating a Linked Database, but Synonyms were the answer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190626.aspx

Comment: The "Note" on that page is noteworthy (!?) "You cannot reference a synonym that is located on a linked server.".  You can't create a synonym for a database either - confused?

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing i tried to do and noticed it failed miserably. Meaning, you cant create a Linked Server "MyLinkedServer", then create a synonym "MySyn" on said server, and call "MyLinkedServer.MySyn". You don't need to use LinkedServers if you're using a synonym anyway, as you have to declare the server on it's creation.

Answer (score 2):

I know, its an old question, but (at least in SQL 2014, but I guess in older versions too) you can set up a linked server with an "alias" and remote queries ([OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) for the database part.

```
USE [master]
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'MyAliasServer', @srvproduct=N'SQLSERVER', 
             @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'MyRealServer1', @catalog=N'database1'
```

Of course you have to set up the security etc. too. After that you could run

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyAliasServer, 'select * from dbo.MyTbl')
```

without specifying a database name (because it is already defined in the linked server connection).

If you script out the linked server (context menu) and replace the server name / database name you could do a switch over between the two servers just by dropping the current and create the other linked server.