# Create view to non-existent table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, view

Is there some way to create a view in a database that links to non-existent tables?

We've just discovered that a data import routine has been failing for a period of time because of a rather large upgrade that accidentally removed a view.

The view (in the database for our product, hosted on a client server) was linked to a table in one of our customers databases, and created by our client for the purpose.

The accidental removal of this view was due to the quantity of database changes (including the creating and dropping of views), and the fact the SQL comparison tool was going to drop the client-specific view was simply missed.

So it would be really useful to be able to create a copy of this view on our local development databases (with full qualified names to the client tables that we obvious don't have access to outside of the live environment) so this doesn't happen again.

(The customer in question is running SQL Server 2008, however this is a product that is also run on 2005 environment for other customers.  So an answer for 2005 would be preferable, but if it's 2008 specific that isn't a problem.)

---

**Update:**

To respond to @Damien's comment...

I understand what you're saying, and creating an empty table that is being linked to in the view would make a lot of sense.

Unfortunately the table in question is hosted not only in a different database, but on a different SQL server.  That would mean that I would have create a new server instance on all our development machine, in order to host this single empty table.  And I would have to do this on quite a number of our clients, resulting in a LOT of practically unused server instances.

I'm really hoping to be able to avoid this, and instead be able to create the view (which obviously will fail in our development environment) but will not be accidentally removed again in the future.

---

**Update 2**

I've taken on board what @Damien has said and implemented this using `Linked Server`... see my answer for more details

Comment: Why can't you create (empty) copies of these tables?

Comment: Because, @Damien, that would involve creating a new server instance, a new database and a new table... all of which I'm not particular keen on doing just for this.  I was hoping that there was some sort of "override" command on the create which tells SQL Server "don't bother checking to see if this exists, just assume it does". I guess not, but I was just hoping

Comment: There's no good solution to this problem but you can either comment "FROM" section in your local VIEW and NULL out field values (e.g. "SELECT NULL AS ClientField1, NULL AS ClientField2, etc /*FROM foo*/ WHERE ClientField1 > X ORDER BY ClientField2", or, even more ugly, create a table which has dots in it's name and refer to that table in your local system (like a table with the name "ClientPC.dbo.ClientTableName", and refer to this in the View. Not posting this as an answer as there may be better solution, but I don't know any, sadly.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, that's pretty much what I thought. I've managed to cobble something together, which I've put as an answer... unless anybody else comes up with a better idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mark says in [his comment under my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955653/create-view-to-non-existent-table#comment28000291_18955653), it doesn't appear to be possible to do this with a `view`.  ("Deferred Name Resolution" exists for `stored procedures`, but not for `views`).

The way I've gotten around it is to roughly follow [@Damien's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955653/create-view-to-non-existent-table#comment27994471_18955653) by creating a new instance on my development machine, which is purely going to be used for these "client specific empty tables".

Then I created a `Linked Server` object to this new instance with an alias of the clients server name (using [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13768230/930393) in order to create the `Linked Server` object), and in the instance I created the appropriately named database and appropriately named table.

The service for this new instance has been set to Manual start, so it shouldn't be taking up and resources - and I can get it up and running when necessary for any future work.

The result is that I now have the `view` in question in my development database, and it "compares" exactly with the `view` in our client database... so it will never (theoretically) be deleted as part of an upgrade again.