# Getting data from 2 servers with 1 connection string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a querystring which takes data from tables on 2 different servers, e.g:

```
select col1.a, col2.a, col1.b, col2.b
from server1.database1.dbo.table1 a
inner join server2.database2.dbo.table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

The connection string points to server1, e.g:

```
<add key="connection_string" value="user id=user_name_goes_here;password=password_goes_here;initial catalog=database1;data source=server1 />
```

If I try to remove server1 from the querystring it works fine, e.g:

```
select col1.a, col2.a, col1.b, col2.b
from database1.dbo.table1 a
inner join server2.database2.dbo.table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

But if I try to remove server2 from the query string:

```
select col1.a, col2.a, col1.b, col2.b
from database1.dbo.table1 a
inner join database2.dbo.table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

I get an error:

> Invalid object name 'database2.dbo.table2'

What needs to be done so I can join tables from 2 different servers without specifying the server name in the querystring?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13768230/3393505

Answer (score 0):

**Synonyms** will fulfill your requirement.

Please check below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187552.aspx

Not sure but may be **linked server** may required.